# Specific range of map in android by using mapView

Tags: android, mapbox

how to show the mapBox map view in specific range in android just like i need to show only Asia pacific in mapView only ,not display full world in mapView android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the zoom level of the map (radius is the radius of the map in meter):

```
double radius = 500.0;

Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng).radius(radius).strokeColor(Color.RED));
circle.setVisible(false);
int zoomLevel = getZoomLevel(circle);
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));

private int getZoomLevel(Circle circle) {
  int zoomLevel = 15;
  if (circle != null) {
    double radius = circle.getRadius();
    double scale = radius / 500;
    zoomLevel = (int) (16 - Math.log(scale) / Math.log(2));
  }
  return zoomLevel;
}
```

Comment: I have two latlng of region where i have to show the map and i ma not using google Api for displaying map,I am using mapBox for that

Comment: You could calculate the center and the distance to each other. Then use this for positioning and zoomind the map.

Comment: @ Philipp E  It's not applicable with mapbox sdk.